# run program with perl or C++

Tags: c++, perl, fork

I am looking for a way to grade C++ programs.

I want to be able to execute numerous programs that will have a standard input/output path, so each program will be required to output and input information at the appropriate time.

What is the best way to do this? I have seen that some people say write a C++ program that calls fork() but my question about that is how do you interact with the same input and output screen? (in other words, once you fork that process, can you feed that process input and view it's output?) Would a perl script work better?

If so, can you give me a few lines of the perl script and what it would look like.

Comment: Perl has a module called Expect, which facilitates Perl interacting with stdio prompting and input in external applications.  Expect::Simple has an easier interface to use, and Test::Expect allows you to create assertions easily that must be met, and then test them using Expect.  The modules work best under non-Windows environments, however.

Comment: [Expect](http://p3rl.org/Expect) is appropriate when the program you want to drive needs a pseudo-terminal. The description mentions only stdin/stdout, for which the modest means of [IPC::Run](http://p3rl.org/IPC::Run) or [IPC::Open3](http://p3rl.org/IPC::Open3) already suffice.

Comment: @daxim: That's a good point.  In that case I would still want to suggest a Test:: module for driving the testing of assertions.  Even Test::More combined with IPC::Run or IPC::Open3 can make it a snap to verify the target code meets a spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the Posix popen or open3 to open the program and interract with its stdin and stdout.  You should be able to do this in any language; personally I would use Ruby and rspec to do the grading.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/popen.html

Be sure to run the students' code as a user with restricted permissions and use a chroot jail!

Comment: Thank you very much! This is going to help out a great bunch! I actually am a better Java programmer and your information helped me towards the Java Process object which basically does the same thing. Thank you for your help!